# Azure Event Hub - Virtual Net Integration - Restrict Reading

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-virtual-network, network-security-groups

Is there a way to restrict the Azure Event Hub with Virtual Net Integration to allow ingress from public and egress to specific VNET ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is currently not possible. The firewall restriction applies to all connections (no matter whether sending or consuming):

> The IP filter rules are applied at the Event Hubs namespace level.
>   Therefore, the rules apply to **all connections** from clients using any
>   supported protocol.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-ip-filtering